# Impossible to step into nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, nuget-package

I have a dotnet7 console app with a nuget package created by my team.

I tried to step into the class from my console app to the package class but I have this window that pop
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B96QE.png)

Though, I did as usual which is to build and Pack the project, grab the .nupkg file and paste it into my localNugetpackage folder that I use for testing and install it.

This time it does not let me step into.

Am I missing something ?

Thank you

I tried to remove the package, reinstall, closing opening VS but same problem.

Comment: That's by-design. NuGet packages are not obligated to contain a copy of their source-code ([they can](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-source-code-link-for-nuget-packages/), but I've only ever seen a minority of packages ever do that).

Comment: As a workaround, Visual Studio should now allow you to decompile assemblies on the go while debugging. Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/decompilation?view=vs-2022.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got it working.